# Peewee ORM query result fn.COUNT is type unicode, not integer

Tags: python, mysql, orm, peewee

Please help me understand behavior of peewee 2.4.5 when talking to MySQL 5.5.  I'm running a simple query to count children associated with a parent; in this case documents at a path.  As plain SQL it boils down to this:

```
select p.name, count(d.file) as child_count 
from path as p, doc as d 
where p.id = d.path_id 
group by p.name
```

The Peewee code uses the fn.COUNT feature, see below for a self-contained example.  The result comes back just fine and with the results I expect, with one exception: the query result object attribute "child_count" is of type unicode instead of integer. In this little example there's 1 row and I get back a string (essentially) '1' instead of the number 1.

I'm confused because in other queries I have done with fn.COUNT the result is of type integer. Is this a feature?  Am I making a silly python mistake here?  Thanks in advance.

```
'''
Example of accessing MySQL from Python using Peewee.
Developed with peewee 2.4.5, pymysql 0.6.3, MySql 5.5
'''
from __future__ import print_function
from peewee import MySQLDatabase, Model, CharField, ForeignKeyField, fn

db = MySQLDatabase(database="test", host="localhost", user="mumble", password="foo")

class MySQLModel(Model):
    '''
    Base class to associate the database object
    '''
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Path(MySQLModel):
    # peewee adds primary key field 'id'
    name = CharField()

class Doc(MySQLModel):
    # peewee adds primary key field 'id'
    path = ForeignKeyField(Path)
    file = CharField()

def main():
    db.connect()
    db.create_tables([Path, Doc], True)
    newpath = Path(name='ab/23')
    newpath.save()
    newdoc1 = Doc(path=newpath.id, file='file1.txt')
    newdoc1.save()
    newdoc2 = Doc(path=newpath.id, file='file2.txt')
    newdoc2.save()
    for row in Path.select():
        print("Path: id=%d, name=%s" % (row.id, row.name))
    for row in Doc.select():
        print("Doc: id=%d, file=%s" % (row.id, row.file))
    # query in plain old SQL:
    # select p.name, count(d.file) from path as p, doc as d where p.id = d.path_id group by p.name
    path_doc_result = (Path
        .select(Path.name, fn.COUNT(Doc.file).alias('child_count'))
        .join(Doc, on=(Path.id == Doc.path)) 
        .group_by(Path.name))
    path_doc_count = len(list(path_doc_result))
    print("Path-doc parent-child result count is %d" % path_doc_count)
    if path_doc_count == 0:
        print("Programmer error, no results!")
    else:
        # get the first one
        d_row = path_doc_result[0]
        #### Why is the child_count attribute not integer? ###
        print("Type of child_count attribute is %s" % type(d_row.child_count))
        print("Path-Doc result: name=%s child_count=%d" % (d_row.name, int(d_row.child_count)))

    newdoc1.delete_instance()
    newdoc2.delete_instance()
    newpath.delete_instance()
    # order matters for foreign keys!
    db.drop_table(Doc)
    db.drop_table(Path)
    db.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peewee functions look at the type of the first argument and attempt to coerce the return value to that type. This makes sense in most cases but I can see why it's causing an issue here.

To work around, just call `fn.COUNT(Doc.file).coerce(False).alias('child_count')`

```
path_doc_result = (Path
    .select(Path.name, fn.COUNT(Doc.file).coerce(False).alias('child_count'))
    .join(Doc, on=(Path.id == Doc.path)) 
    .group_by(Path.name))
```

Comment: Ok fn.COUNT(CharField) yields a result that is coerced to a String, and I can stop the coercion with .coerce(False).   Now that I understand what's going on, I changed the code to count the Doc.path field which is integer, and the result is integer. Thanks.

Comment: You might mark this as the correct answer so anyone in the future will see how to fix it.